# How to extract data from a Pandas DataFrame based on column values on another DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my two Multiindex dataframes:

```
    df1:
    Index_0 Index_1         KEYS           FLOOR    NBVAL   ACCBV
     116    1687    X425531.25Y6407133.75   505.5   184.3   1690.7
     117    1906    X425531.25Y6407141.25   505.0    56.4   2243.4
     118    2141    X425531.25Y6407148.75   504.5    29.7   2712.7


    df2:
     Index0 Index1         KEYS             FLOOR    NBVAL   ACCBV   ACCNB   ACCPB
      116   726     X425531.25Y6407133.75   508.5   -133.0  -133.0  -133.0     0.0
      116   854     X425531.25Y6407133.75   508       18.2  -114.8  -133.0    18.2
      116   994     X425531.25Y6407133.75   507.5    233.7   118.9  -133.0   251.9
      116   1146    X425531.25Y6407133.75   507     -125.0    -6.1  -258.0   251.9
      116   1313    X425531.25Y6407133.75   506.5    467.0   460.9  -258.0   718.9
      116   1493    X425531.25Y6407133.75   506      374.2   835.1  -258.0  1093.1
      116   1687    X425531.25Y6407133.75   505.5   -122.0   713.1  -380.0  1093.1
      116   1895    X425531.25Y6407133.75   505     -121.2   591.8  -501.2  1093.1
      117   734     X425531.25Y6407141.25   508.5   -132.1  -132.1  -132.1     0.0
      117   862     X425531.25Y6407141.25   508       -0.5  -132.6  -132.6     0.0
      117   1003    X425531.25Y6407141.25   507.5    312.4   179.8  -132.6   312.4
      117   1155    X425531.25Y6407141.25   507      653.0   832.8  -132.6   965.4
      117   1323    X425531.25Y6407141.25   506.5    564.1  1396.8  -132.6  1529.5
      117   1503    X425531.25Y6407141.25   506      436.2  1833.0  -132.6  1965.6
      117   1698    X425531.25Y6407141.25   505.5    353.9  2187.0  -132.6  2319.6
      117   1906    X425531.25Y6407141.25   505       56.4  2243.4  -132.6  2376.0
      117   2129    X425531.25Y6407141.25   504.5   -238.6  2004.8  -371.2  2376.0
      118   742     X425531.25Y6407148.75   508.5   -125.6  -125.6  -125.6     0.0
      118   870     X425531.25Y6407148.75   508      -14.0  -139.6  -139.6     0.0
      118   1012    X425531.25Y6407148.75   507.5    494.1   354.5  -139.6   494.1
      118   1164    X425531.25Y6407148.75   507      682.0  1036.5  -139.6  1176.1
      118   1333    X425531.25Y6407148.75   506.5    597.0  1633.5  -139.6  1773.1
      118   1513    X425531.25Y6407148.75   506      474.1  2107.6  -139.6  2247.2
      118   1709    X425531.25Y6407148.75   505.5    373.6  2481.2  -139.6  2620.8
      118   1917    X425531.25Y6407148.75   505      201.7  2683.0  -139.6  2822.6
      118   2141    X425531.25Y6407148.75   504.5     29.7  2712.7  -139.6  2852.3
      118   2380    X425531.25Y6407148.75   504     -341.3  2371.4  -480.9  2852.3
```

I'm somehow new to Python and I managed to get to this point where I got the two DataFrames above however I'm struggling to move forward. Hence my questions below:

First, how can I accumulate 'ACCNB' from 'NBVAL' only if the latter is negative.(The example above was calculated in MS Excel).
Second, how can I accumulate 'ACCPB' from 'NBVAL' only if the latter is positive.(Also calculated using Excel).
Third, how can I extract the rows from df2 that have the item 'FLOOR' greater or equal to 'FLOOR' in df1 when Index0 in df1 matches Index0 in df2?
df1 is derived from df2 and the Multiindex in df2 was created using groupby (by='KEYS'...).

Below is the desired output:

```
     df3:
     Index0 Index1          KEYS            FLOOR    NBVAL   ACCBV   ACCNB   ACCPB
      116   726     X425531.25Y6407133.75   508.5   -133.0  -133.0  -133.0     0.0
      116   854     X425531.25Y6407133.75   508       18.2  -114.8  -133.0    18.2
      116   994     X425531.25Y6407133.75   507.5    233.7   118.9  -133.0   251.9
      116   1146    X425531.25Y6407133.75   507     -125.0    -6.1  -258.0   251.9
      116   1313    X425531.25Y6407133.75   506.5    467.0   460.9  -258.0   718.9
      116   1493    X425531.25Y6407133.75   506      374.2   835.1  -258.0  1093.1
      117   734     X425531.25Y6407141.25   508.5   -132.1  -132.1  -132.1     0.0
      117   862     X425531.25Y6407141.25   508       -0.5  -132.6  -132.6     0.0
      117   1003    X425531.25Y6407141.25   507.5    312.4   179.8  -132.6   312.4
      117   1155    X425531.25Y6407141.25   507      653.0   832.8  -132.6   965.4
      117   1323    X425531.25Y6407141.25   506.5    564.1  1396.8  -132.6  1529.5
      117   1503    X425531.25Y6407141.25   506      436.2  1833.0  -132.6  1965.6
      117   1698    X425531.25Y6407141.25   505.5    353.9  2187.0  -132.6  2319.6
      117   1906    X425531.25Y6407141.25   505       56.4  2243.4  -132.6  2376.0
      118   742     X425531.25Y6407148.75   508.5   -125.6  -125.6  -125.6     0.0
      118   870     X425531.25Y6407148.75   508      -14.0  -139.6  -139.6     0.0
      118   1012    X425531.25Y6407148.75   507.5    494.1   354.5  -139.6   494.1
      118   1164    X425531.25Y6407148.75   507      682.0  1036.5  -139.6  1176.1
      118   1333    X425531.25Y6407148.75   506.5    597.0  1633.5  -139.6  1773.1
      118   1513    X425531.25Y6407148.75   506      474.1  2107.6  -139.6  2247.2
      118   1709    X425531.25Y6407148.75   505.5    373.6  2481.2  -139.6  2620.8
      118   1917    X425531.25Y6407148.75   505      201.7  2683.0  -139.6  2822.6
      118   2141    X425531.25Y6407148.75   504.5     29.7  2712.7  -139.6  2852.3
```

Apologies for the size of the examples...

Comment: I'm really confused reading your problem description. What does "accumulate ACCNB from NBVAL" mean? Take `KEYS == X425531.25Y6407133.75` for example: how did you go from 8 rows in `df2` to 6 in `df3`? Why did you drop the last two rows in that group (index `116, 1687` and `116, 1895`)

Comment: @Code Different Thanks for the reply. What I want is a cumulative sum of the negative values of NBVAL to be placed on column ACCNB. If a NBVAL value is positive, then it should be accumulated on the ACCPB column. The reason why I dropped the two rows is because I want only the rows where the ACCBV is at its max value and the rows where FLOOR is greater or equal than where ACCBV is at its max value for each group. For instance, on group 116, I want Index1 from 726 to 1493 given this last row has the highest ACCBV value (835.1). FYI The FLOOR column, is sorted in descending order by group.